# modrewrite for smart URL's | multiple variables?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

What is the best way to accomplish that?

Im planning to do some kind of smart modrewrite + a function to grab variable name from the URL.

For example:

A URL like:
domain.com/page-blog/id-5/title-a_blog_title/date-2011_08_05

Would return:

```
$urlvariable = page-blog/id-5/title-a_blog_title/date-2011_08_05
```

Than, I will run a function that will parse the $urlvariable and return

```
$urlvariable['page'] = blog
$urlvariable['id'] = 5
$urlvariable['title'] = a_blog_title
$urlvariable['date'] = 2011_08_05
```

But the rewrite should be able to handle smaller or bigger urls like:
domain.com/page-blog/id-5/

returning:

```
$urlvariable = page-blog/id-5/
```

or also:
domain.com/page-blog/id-5/title-a_blog_title/date-2011_08_05/var1-foo/var2-bar/var3-xpto/var4-xyz etc ...

```
$urlvariable = page-blog/id-5/title-a_blog_title/date-2011_08_05/var1-foo/var2-bar/var3-xpto/var4-xyz
```

Any way to do that? What would be the expression for rewrite?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As for me, the best way is to route all request to your php/another_language script and then use something like this:

```
for($i=1,$arr=explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),$s=count($arr);$i<$s;++$i){  //avoid 0(empty part) and 1(script name)
     $tmp=explode(' ',$arr[$i]);
     $get[$tmp[0]]=$tmp[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Im actually looking for the modrewrite expression to use, the code that goes inside the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

RiaD has the right idea, using `explode` rather than regexps (since regexps are slower).

However, you might want to use regular expressions anyway to "normalize" the URL. But after that you can still use `explode` for a tiny speed gain, or do something like this

```
$url = "page-blog/id-5/blank-/title-a_blog_title/date-2011_08_05/var1-foo/var2-bar/var3-xpto/var4-xyz";

$url = preg_replace("~//+~", '/', $url); // remove multiple consequtive slashes

$params = array();
if( preg_match_all("~(\w+)-([^/]*)~", $url, $params) ) {
    $params = array_combine($params[1], $params[2]);
    print_r($params);
}
```

That will print:

```
Array(
    [page] => blog
    [id] => 5
    [blank] => 
    [title] => a_blog_title
    [date] => 2011_08_05
    [var1] => foo
    [var2] => bar
    [var3] => xpto
    [var4] => xyz
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but Im actually looking for the modrewrite expression to use, the code that goes inside the .htaccess file.